# How can i create range seek bar in android java with indicator?

Tags: java, android, material-components-android, android-seekbar, android-slider

I want to create range seekbar in my app. But i can't create perfectly seekbar according to image. How can i create Please tell me any one. Thanks
[image: example]

Comment: use this library - https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `RangeSlider` provided by the Material Components library:

```
        <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
            app:labelBehavior="withinBounds"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="10000"
            app:values="@array/initial_slider_values"
        />
```

with:

```
<resources>
  <array name="initial_slider_values">
    <item>2000</item>
    <item>3500</item>
  </array>
</resources>
```

[image]

You can also use the method `setValues()`:

```
RangeSlider slider = findViewById(R.id.slider);
slider.setValues(2000f,3500f);
```

Comment: Links to the official doc and guidelines : https://material.io/components/sliders/android

Comment: How show values with seekbar

Comment: Hi Thanks for posting this can you please help me can we should Time Interval Like 
1am-2Pm in start and end  interval